# Create an index column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I want to create a index column in Power BI but that column must have a string and a number. For example: c1,c2,c3... and not just 1,2,3...

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add the index column in Power Query, then choose [Add Column From Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/column-from-example), and enter a few values for the new column.  Power Query will figure out the calculated column formula for you.  You can then remove the initial index column and rename the new index column.

Comment: But my column has 564 rows.. do i need to write the 564 different values?

Comment: No, with "Add Column From Examples" you manually enter a few and Power BI figures out the formula for you.  You can always write the calculated column formula yourself. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-language-specification

Comment: it's working! Thank you very much